# add sharepoint sync via CLI

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How do I sync an Office 365 Sharepoint/OneDrive via command line?

I have this URL `https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/teams/<SharePointName>/<LibraryName>/<Folder>` and I want to add this link to the local OneDrive sync service with a command line/powershell command

I've found sources which suggest to use

```
start "odopen://sync/?siteId=GUID&webId=GUID&listId=GUID&userEmail=$upn&webUrl=https://company.sharepoint.com/&webtitle=Company&listtitle=Documents"
```

but it is not clear to me where to get the different ids from. My tests always crashed the OneDrive sync service

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following script to get the ids you need in your script:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server 
Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server 
Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Config Parameters
$SiteURL= "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/CaseTest1"
$ListName = "xxxxx"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential

Try {
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)
 
#Get the List, Site and Web Objects
$List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$Ctx.Load($List)
$Ctx.Load($Ctx.Site)
$Ctx.Load($Ctx.Web)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Get siteid, webid and listid
Write-host -f Green "Site ID:"$Ctx.Site.Id
Write-host -f Green "Web ID:"$Ctx.Web.Id
Write-host -f Green "List ID:"$List.Id
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

After running the script and get the ids, replace them into your script and it’ll work fine then.

Comment: I don't have Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll installed, where do I get it from? I've tried this one https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038 but this was apparently the wrong package

Comment: Could you give me specific error messages? Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll is included in the file downloaded via that link.

Comment: I reinstalled the package and now the dlls are at said location, don't ask me why. Now it stops furter down during ExecuteQuery() with "The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system". My login/passw is correct, I've checked that by using wrong credentials for testing, where I'd get a different error message. Could be that I'm forced to use MFA?